# Error in asp.net while testing web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a web service that should pull about 80 records from SQL database. However recently it started giving me out of memory error. 
When I debug it - it shows me the web service on the list, once I run it - get the error below.

**webmethod:**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Getting Weekly Events by Facility, future events from sunday", CacheDuration = 600)]
public List<EventViewModel> GetWeeklyEvents(string facilityNumber, DateTime StDate)
{

    var db = new DS_AIMDataContext();
    var eventList = from evt in db.GetPublishedEventsFromSundayByFacility(facilityNumber, StDate)
        select new EventViewModel
        {
            EventName = evt.ActName,
            EventNameSpanish = evt.ActNameSp,
            EventDescription = evt.ActDescription,
            EventDescrSpanish = evt.ActDescrSp,
            StDate = evt.EventStart.Value,
            EndDate = evt.EventEnd.Value,
            EventCategory = evt.CategoryName,
            EventCatID = evt.ActCategID.Value,
            EventType = evt.ActType,
            EventLocation = evt.LocName,
            EventLeader = evt.LeaderName,
            EventCategorySp = evt.CategoryNameSp,
            EventTypeSp = evt.ActTypeSp,
            EventRecurrenceRule = evt.RecurrenceRule,
            EventPhoto1 = evt.Photo1 == null ? null : evt.Photo1.ToArray(),
            EventPhoto2 = evt.Photo2 == null ? null : evt.Photo2.ToArray(),
            EventPhoto3 = evt.Photo3 == null ? null : evt.Photo3.ToArray()
        };
    return eventList.ToList();
}
```

> The function itself:

```
public IEnumerable<tblEventsWithRecurr> GetPublishedEventsFromSundayByFacility(string facN, DateTime StDate)
{
    var eventList = from evt in this.tblEventsWithRecurrs
        orderby Convert.ToDateTime(evt.EventStart.ToString()).Day, Convert.ToDateTime(evt.EventStart.ToString()).Hour, Convert.ToDateTime(evt.EventStart.ToString()).Minute
        where (evt.FacN == facN && evt.EventStatus == "Final" && evt.EventStart >= StDate && evt.EventStart <= StDate.AddDays(31))
        select evt;
    return eventList;
}
```

> Error that I'm getting is below:
>
> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace: 
>   [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
>      System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value) +93
>      System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value) +90
>      System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +326
>      Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.ArteryFilter.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +61
>      System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +9641608
>      System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +104
>      System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +58
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Comment: Have you got Browser Link enabled? If so, does turning it off help?

Comment: have you looked at the system resources to see what else is taking up the memory?  If this has been working ok up until now and nothing in your server has, what else has been added to the hosting machine?

Comment: does it happen on the first call? or subsequent calls?

Comment: Yes, Browser link was enabled. And once I disabled it - the error disappeared... Thank you for the tip!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

First, how big are your Photo files - you have 3 photo's you're sending back. It would not be difficult to imagine a dozen very large photos on all of your results to max out whatever memory you have going on.

Secondly:

You may want to consider disposing of your datacontext.

Currently you have:

```
var db = new DS_AIMDataContext();
```

And this is never explicitly disposed, meaning the GC will eventually get to it, where you could instruct it to be disposed of the moment you are finished with it.

So try that line to:

```
using (DS_AIMDataContext db = new DS_AIMDataContext()){
   // all of your eventList projection
   // and your return statement
}
```

This will call Dispose as soon as your method completes and will hopefully free up memory.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips. I agree that was an issue with too many pictures, some were large size. I had added the line "using" as was suggested, as well as disabled "Browser Link". No more errors. Thank you all!